# Securing Play's REST APIs

Tags: backbone.js, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to use `Play 2.x` with `backbone.js` for a project. My intention is to create RESTful APIs at the server end (all response bodies are in JSON and all request bodies are in JSON also).

I would like to use Facebook OAuth (server side) to authenticate my requests. For this purpose I'm using [play-authorize](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/) for OAuth. The issue I am having is that the user session information is stored in the Session Object in Play. I don't really want to use play-templates in my HTML code, how can I use the Session Object on the client side without the play-templates.

Also what measures can I use to prevent CSRF/XSS attacks while using Play.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but be aware that Play is stateless. That means that the "Session" is stored in a cookie that gets sent to the server. You can store string values to that cookie and access them from the browser.

Now, you don't want to store critical values in there, but something that the server side code recognizes and lets you work with to solve your problem.

Comment: actually I had related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964102/access-playframework-session-in-javascript about the inability to access the play session on client side. I also understand that the play cookie is encrypted and hence I would not be able to read it. I want to pass the cookie along in the HTTP requests going forward on this page but can't access it. That would help a bit.

Comment: cookie values are signed with a secret key so the client can’t modify the cookie data (or it will be invalidated). I don't think they are encrypted. Which means you should be able to get the value (granted, never tried)