# Access Playframework Session in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, playframework-2.0

I am using Play 2.0.3 / 2.0.4. I create a cookie on the server side (default name = PLAY_SESSION) and am trying to access it in javascript.

I have set the application.session.httpOnly=false in application.conf file. However accessing the cookie in javascript return null. Looking up the cookie in Chrome says

Accessible to script:   No (HttpOnly)

Not sure why the cookie is not marked accessible to script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct key in application.conf file to use is `session.httpOnly`.
This key was added in [this commit](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/commit/c2f4703940c1cb9f2d52e5533b9847546dfae1ef).